# How to add image in a report by using an existing professional template image

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can I add an image in a report by using an existing professional template image?

the image object is report.template.settings

the filed name is footer_logo

I try this code not work for me

```
<span t-field="report.template.settings.footer_logo" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use image like this:

```
<img t-att-src="report.template.settings.footer_logo"/>
```